# Импорт C++ библиотеки неверно подсвечивает PyCharm

Tags: python, c++, pycharm, ide, boost.python

Импортирую свою dll-обёртку над C++ библиотекой из текущей директории:

```
import my_lib
```

Код запускается и работает, однако PyCharm подчёркивает красным, якобы не найден такой модуль. Можно ли как-то избавиться от этого false positive?

Comment: Может PyCharm ожидает увидеть __init__ в каталоге?

Comment: @Александр не, всё равно подчёркивает